# GWT: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: gwt

I have a problem with my GWT project and I didn't found a solution to it.
When I try to compile, I've got those lines:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger$Type.values()[Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger$Type;
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.arg.ArgHandlerLogLevel.computeOptionsString(ArgHandlerLogLevel.java:30)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.arg.ArgHandlerLogLevel.<clinit>(ArgHandlerLogLevel.java:26)
at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileArgProcessor.<init>(CompileArgProcessor.java:25)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile$ArgProcessor.<init>(Precompile.java:105)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$ArgProcessor.<init>(Compiler.java:55)
at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:151)
```

Configurations:
GWT SDK 2.4, 
eclipse ,
smartgwt.

It used to work fine, but suddently something got wrong
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` exception means that the class was found but it has an incorrect version not having the requested method.

In this case it seems you have in your classpath an old gwt-dev previous to the commit [r2313](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?spec=svn2313&r=2313).

So verify your classpath.

Comment: Right Manolo.Thank you for the answer